# Getting Bad request for POST request using Axios and CORS in Django and react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, django-cors-headers

I made a post request to this url http://localhost:8000/api/auth/users/ on postman . It was successful. However, trying the same thing on my react front end produces a 400 (bad request error). It also says Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Here's my code AuthAPi.js:

```
import API from "./API"; 

const config = {
  headers :{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
   }
}

const signIn = (email, password) => API.post("/auth/users/", {
  params : {
    email : email,
    password : password 
    
  },
},
  config
)
.Catch((error) => console.log( error.message ) );

export { signIn };
```

and API.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api`,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

I've tried several links without solutions. I'd be glad to get assistance here.

There is below a screenshot a console log, Network log and Django server log:

[image: A Console log]

[image: Network part 1]

[image: Network part 2]

[image: Network part 3]

[image: Log of Django server]

Comment: Could you share your Django code? The bad request (400) error is not due to CORS policy.

Comment: Which part or file  of the Django code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
API.post("/auth/users/", {
  params : {
    email : email,
    password : password 
  }
}
```

You’re passing an object which contains an object to axios as post data. Axios doesn’t mind, but your server no-likey. Instead, try:

```
API.post("/auth/users/", {
  email : email,
  password : password 
}, config)
```

This should work. If you want to pass in as a single object, you need to declare it outside of the api call:

```
let postData = {
  email: email,
  password: password
}
API.post("/auth/users/", postData, config)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it this way and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it still the same

Comment: We need to see the response and request objects. You’ll find them in the network tab in your dev tools. Update your question with screenshots or copy the entire text (headers and body data). That way we’ll be able to troubleshoot a little further.

Comment: Thanks, I have just added images @Nick Dawes

Answer (score 1):

`params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request

The signature of `post` instance method that you used is `axios#post(url[, data[, config]])`, thus you should make your request like this

```
const signIn = (email, password) => API.post("/auth/users/", {
    email : email,
    password : password 
  },
  config
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it this way and it still doesn't work.